# Generate new variable based on table of conditions

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to write a loop in **R** that creates a new variable based on a table of conditional outcomes.

I have four treatment groups (A, B, C, D). Each treatment group pays a different price at three different time periods (day, dinner, night).

```
Treatment Group    Day Price      Dinnertime Price       Night Price
A                     10                 20                   7
B                     11                 25                   8
C                     12                 30                   9
D                     13                 35                   10
```

The time period is recorded as a given "hour" (day is hours 8-17, dinner is from 17-19 and night is from 19-0 and 0-8).

```
               Hour        Usage
   Person 1      1            0
   Person 1      2            0
   Person 2      20           5
   Person 3      17           6
```

Based on both treatment group (A, B, C and D) and time of day (night, day, dinnertime), I would like to create a new vector of prices.

Ideally, I would create dummy variables for each of the time periods (day, night and dinner) based on these hourly conditions. However, my data set is pretty large (24 observations per person per day) so I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

In plain language, I want this:

```
 if group==A & time==night, then price=7 --> and this information saved in a new variable "price"
```

Any advice?

Edit: Question is about the loop with two conditions. Is there a way to refer this directly to the data-frame with the treatment groups and tariffs or do I just need to write it manually?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the price comes from, but you can use `cut()` to refactor the hours into the time of the day

Comment: Price is just determined by the treatment group. Thanks for the tip. What kind of loop can I run with this when I have two conditions? I want it to just refer to the data frame with the treatment groups rather than individually specify the conditions

Comment: i think you need to give some more clarification. Like: Which data frames are already available (both?) and what is your desired output? Do you want to have the price variable in the second data frame?

Comment: Yes, sorry - both data frames are already available. As shown above, there are different prices depending on the time of day and the treatment group 

I am trying to create a list of prices that corresponds to this time slot and treatment (so a new variable). So if time is 8am and treatment group A, then the price is x. It's not a complicated calculation but I'm just now sure how to tell R how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have some way of including a column for the group each person belongs to in the dataframe with the transactions on it. Then something like this may work for you.

```
df.pricing <- structure(list(Treatment.Group = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Day.Price = 10:13, 
                             Dinnertime.Price = c(20L, 25L, 30L, 35L), Night.Price = 7:10), 
                        .Names = c("Treatment.Group", "Day.Price", "Dinnertime.Price", "Night.Price"), 
                        class = "data.frame", 
                        row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df.transactions <- structure(list(Person = c("Person1", "Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4"), 
                                  Hour = c(1L, 2L, 20L, 17L, 9L), 
                                  Usage = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 2L)), 
                             .Names = c("Person", "Hour", "Usage"), 
                             class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

# Add the group that each person belongs to
df.transactions$group <- c("A","A","B","C","D")

# Get the transaction price
df.transactions$price <- apply(df.transactions, 1, function(x){
                                                 hour <- as.numeric(x[["Hour"]])
                                                 price <- ifelse(hour >= 8 & hour <= 16, df.pricing[df.pricing$Treatment.Group == x[["group"]], "Day.Price"],
                                                                 ifelse((hour > 16 & hour <= 18), df.pricing[df.pricing$Treatment.Group == x[["group"]], "Dinnertime.Price"],
                                                                        df.pricing[df.pricing$Treatment.Group == x[["group"]], "Night.Price"]))})
```